TXS0108E high level on input when high on OE
I have TX0108E connected to the WEMOS D1-mini as on diagram:

But my WeMOS does not boot, I checked voltages and D6,D7,D8 are high.
Boot fails when D8 is high on boot. Is it OK that current flows from OE to input pins? This is my first SMD soldering so I could overheat device, (pins are not soldered together).
I would like to know If I should change my circuit or just try another chip?

Current does not flow from OE to input pins.
The TXS0108 has internal pull-up resistors to supplies and they are enabled when OE is high.
So TXS0108 is just wrong chip or you need a different circuit where OE is low until the device has booted.
It is not clear what you want to do with the TXS0108 but it might be simply the wrong chip to do what you want or more complex to use than what you expected.

Ok. So it unlocks flow from VCCA to input pin. I would just cut out D8 pin. D6 and D7  are enough for me.
